# How to set virtual users in load runner in HP ALM 12.05

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, alm, vugen

I have one VuGen script(recorded script) which i need to execute with Virtual users. Currently i am able to import it and also found play button (after several attempts). But the problem is where should i need to mention the Virtual user number.
Provide some tutorial/ link for the latest ALM

Comment: IF your manager is asking you to engage in this activity then they owe you training and a mentor until you can be self sufficient in the role.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the default edit view for your test, the *"Groups and Workload"* tab in the *Performance Test Designer* window.
If you already added your script, you will find an entry for it in the *"Groups"* grid.

In that grid there's also a column for *"Vusers"*. For your script the value will be set to `1` by default. If you want **to increase that number, just double-click on the grid** to edit the value. Surprisingly, you won't find that option in the script's Runtime Settings or any other dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Best training site would be youtube :), as for how to add X amount of users, this is done in the controller, there you can schedule when the users start running, if all at once or every 1, 2, 3 minutes etc.

There are also companies that offer training when needed and help you with script development, google for iDeliver inc ;).